# How to set the params in http options with key and value by passing id dynamically as received from the serve r in calling the API

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular8, rest

I am stucking in set the params in http options in calling the API ,it is showing the errors that *no overload is required* and also *An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name in strict mode.*I want to set the params in calling the API.

**.service.ts**

```
senrstart( token) {
  let httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Token ' + token
    }),

  params: new HttpParams()
     
  params.set('id', this.jammers.name)


  }
    
 this.http.get(environment.apiUrl+'/api/sensors/start?id', httpOptions).subscribe(
    (senrst:any[])=>{

     localStorage.setItem("senrst",JSON.stringify(senrst));
    console.log("senrstart:",JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("senrst")))
```

**.component.ts**

```
senrstart(){
  this.senrstart=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("senrstart"));
console.log("senrstart",this.senrstart)
}
```

For the above code I want to set the params by passing the id dynamically with key:id and value is sensor.name which I recieved from backend.

Comment: Does your code passed compilation? The httpOptions has two lines of params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass array of ids to server:

1. you could JSON.stringify it before sending:

   ```
   params: new HttpParams().set('id', JSON.stringify(this.jammers.map(itm => itm.name)))
   ```

   And accept it in server:

   ```
   JSON.parse(yourdata)
   ```
2. Or you can pass like below:

   ```
   let httpParams = new HttpParams();
   this.jammers.forEach(itm => {
     httpParams = httpParams.append('id[]', itm.name);
   });
   ```

Comment: Both are same right ?  Can you help m e how to use this params

Comment: The params set like {params: new HttpParams().set('id', this.jammers.name)} should be ok. I'm not sure if the headers is needed here.

Comment: Thanks,I have made the corrections as you mentioned while executing showing error like Property 'name' does not exist on type 'any[]' .Is it required to declare the jammers.name in a seperate variable than use that name in id value? if yes then how to represent that variable because that jammers.name is I received from the backend form another API.

Comment: Do you still have question on this? Regarding the message 'showing error like Property 'name' does not exist on type 'any[]' ', what's the type of this.jammers ? it seems this is an array, is this you wanted? maybe you need to console log the this.jammers

Comment: Yes jammers is an array that I received from the backend :In console.log I received the jammers array as 0: {name: "J3", latitude: "51.12", longitude: "90.456"}
1: {name: "J2", latitude: "57.12", longitude: "66.456"}
2: {name: "J1", latitude: "59.12", longitude: "92.456"} this is the array i recieved from the backend  .So I want to pass the jammer name as id value in params .

Comment: all names? or only one item name

Comment: All names. Passing the name of the jammer as id, because the names will be increasing in future as received from the server

Comment: All names like {id: ['J1', 'J2', 'J3']}? If yes, params: new HttpParams().set('id', this.jammers.map(itm => itm.name))

Comment: Thanks,I have Placed the code what you said params:new HttpParams().set('id', this.jammers.map(itm => itm.name));it is showing only one error that is Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Canyou help me to overcome this error.Becaus I have'nt involved in this senario.

Comment: This is because HttpParams().set does not accept array as an argument. There are several ways to solve the issue. The easiest way is to params: new HttpParams().set('id', JSON.stringify( this.jammers.map(itm => itm.name))), and use JSON.parse method to convert it back to JSON.

Comment: Thank you very much .Working not showing any errors but in console it is not showing all the names that are started ```

Comment: Thank you very much .Working, not showing any errors but in console it is not showing all the names that are started .in console it is showing :{action: " jammer started",status: true}  My goal is it has to show the jammer names because I am passing jammer names as id valucan you give me the code for getting to start the jammer with particular jammer name .where i received from the backend